# Concept for type name int

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I am trying to write a concept for type name `int` but not been able to find one. I can't think of any operation that is valid just on `int` type and not valid for `double`, `float`, etc. Is it possible to write this with current standards? Thank you in advance.

Note: My aim is to make this code work by fixing the part with question marks. If parameters are `int` then `operation` function returns the sum of them, if parameters are not `int` then the function returns their product.

```
template<typename T>
concept Int = requires(T t){
    ????????
};

template<typename T>
auto operation(T t1, T t2)
{
    if constexpr(!Int<T>)
        return t1 * t2;
    else
        return t1 + t2;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: You use a concept to restrict the template arguments. If you are ok with float and double, why bother use a concept at all? A simple template will be fine.

Comment: `std::same_as<T, int>`? but why would you write a concept? it's `if constexpr(std::is_same<T, int>::value)`? I do not think concept "convert"s to boolean, I think `if (Integer<T>)`  is not going to work.

Comment: bitshift and modulus valid only on integrals. also type_traits already have identifications for int and others

Comment: Yes @KamilCuk you are right, thank you for the answer, I should probably use std::same_as, but still wondering whether it's possible to write a concept for integers

Comment: *"can't think of any operation that is valid just on int"* A concept doesn't have to use `requires`, any boolean expression will work. You can write something like `template <typename T> concept foo = std::is_same_v<T, int>;` (or better using `std::same_as`)

Comment: @KamilCuk Concepts (with template args) can be used as booleans.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Oh I was thinking that I must use `requires` keyword `concept Integer = std::same_as<T, int>;` works perfect thanks!

Comment: Are you looking to restrict to `int` itself, built-in integer types of all sizes (e.g. `uint64_t`, `uint_fast8_t`, `short`, etc.), or allowing anything "`int`-like", e.g. `mpz_class` from GMP?

Comment: `requires` is a separate thing, you can use it anywhere you need a `bool`. `if (requires{...})` is valid, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concepts are defined by boolean expressions

```
template<typename T>
concept Int = std::is_same_v<T, int>;
```

But due to [concept ordering issues](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints#Partial_ordering_of_constraints), it's better to use

```
template<typename T>
concept Int = std::same_as<T, int>;
```

However, you should always use simpler tools when they suffice. In your case, simply overloading is fine

```
auto operation(auto t1, auto t2)
{
    return t1 * t2;
}

auto operation(int t1, int t2)
{
    return t1 + t2;
}
```

Notably, [don't specialize your functions](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm), it's most often wrong.